# Puncture in tube with sealant

Tags: tire, innertube

Had a thorn in my tyre last night, the tube has sealant in it, which worked.
How long is it likely to last, or should I change/repair the tube as soon as possible. 
28 mm almost slick tyres running with 110 psi.

To clarify, the tyre has an innertube that came with sealant already inside the tube. I removed the thorn and the hole sealed, it is still holding pressure. The recommended pressure for the tyre is up to 120 psi.

Comment: Unless you are very heavy there shouldn't be a need to run as much as 110psi in a 28mm.  Most people will run 28's at 70-80psi

Comment: Could you please clarify if this is a tube in a tyre, or a tubeless tyre?  Commenters seem unsure.

Comment: This question is now 8 months old.  Can you please add an answer of your own describing what you did and how it worked for you?   Feel free to accept your own answer by clicking the tick/check box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tube lasted for about 2months with no loss of pressure, then the tyre failed.
Have replaced both tyres and innertubes.

Answer (score 5):

**Hypothetically yes, it will last a while** - if a sealant is used in a tube and the tire subsequently gets a puncture, you must remove the penetrating object or it will flex in the tire, continually un-sealing the hole and shredding the tube.

If you believe you completely removed whatever caused the puncture and the sealant plugged the hole and you were able to continue your ride, that's great!

Some steps to further make sure the sealant will hold for future use:

1. If significant sealant was lost during the puncture and you have a removable valve core, add more sealant.
2. If you are truly concerned if the tube will stay plugged you can add glitter through the valve core. This helps plug holes, especially depending on the type of sealant you are using.
3. Reattach the valve core and inflate the tire.
4. Spin the wheel to mimic the motion of rolling down the road.

Given enough time, most sealants cease to be active and should be cleaned out; if they solidify, they unbalance the tire with useless weight concentrated in a single spot. On a tire with an inner tube, including a tubular, you’ll need to remove the sealant through the valve, which requires removing the valve core, and ideally rinsing and sucking it out. That is a lot of work if it is a tube in a clincher wheel. So you could always deflate the tire, remove the tube and insert a brand new tube and repeat the steps listed above.

Answer (score -5):

The answer to your question is that, if it's leaking air, it can last a little while, but I believe you should have it repaired as soon as possible. I don't have tubeless tires but I have done a ton of research on the matter. There are some kits around to help you if you are new to the subject. Generally, if you think that is is not leaking any air then you are very lucky my friend and do not need to pay any attention.

Comment: Can you expand your answer beyond just posting link?

Comment: This isn't exactly relevant -- this guy is dealing with tubeless tires.

Comment: All I see is a broken image symbol - can you turn this into an answer?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained. That way, the answer is still valid if the link dies. Please summarize what information is contained in the link within the body of your answer. Otherwise, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am very sorry that I didn't help you and I would like to delete the answer myself. How do I do that?

Comment: Basically, this answer says, "Well, I don't really know, but I've read on the internet that the sealant hasn't sealed the hole, you'll need to repair the tube." Thank you, Captain Obvious.